# ¿Cómo activar la flecha de atrás?

Tags: android

¿Cómo puedo activar la flecha de atrás que esta en el `action bar` en todas las actividades?

Lo logré hacer de la segunda a la primera actividad pero no funciona de tercera a segunda ...

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_busqueda);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

y es mi ItemMenu

```
  case android.R.id.home:
        if (getParentActivityIntent() == null) {

            onBackPressed();
        }
```

Comment: Hola Wid. Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado para pasar de la segunda a la primera? Sin tu codigo es muy amplio

Comment: Tienes que mostrarnos que haz intentado para poder ayudarte.

Comment: ademas de lo que comentan arriba solo quería dejar el comentario de que implementar un botón "atrás" es una mala practica y debería ser evitada en Android a menos que la situación lo amerite por algún caso especial.

Answer (score 1):

Como activar la flecha para todas las actividades:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Para que puedas habilitar la flecha, es importante que tu Activity extienda de `AppCompatActivity` :

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    // Obtiene toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // agrega flecha
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

---

> Lo logré hacer de la segunda a la primera actividad pero no funciona
>   de tercera a segunda

En este caso debes asegurar que la tercera Activity se abra a partir de la segunda, pero la segunda no sea finalizada mediante el método:

```
finish();
```

Comment: muchas gracias Jorgesys lo había resuelto :)